# SOAP Request Error (The requested operation was rejected)

Tags: soap, xmlhttprequest, http-post, soapui, soap-client

I sent a request via postman and it works fine and received a response, but in other environment I received an error message as below.

```
Url as e.g. https://URL/secure?Username=ABCD&Password=ABCD
```

Header:

```
Content-Type: text/xml
Accept: application/json, text/xml, application/xml, */*, application/soap+xml
User-Agent: APP
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
SOAPAction: URL
Username: ABCD
Password: ABCD
ClientID: 123
OrgUnitGuid: abc-1234
OrgUnitID: 123
```

Body as example:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:post="url" xmlns:arr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" xmlns:core="http://Core.Model" xmlns:ser="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:UsernameToken>
                <wsse:Username>ABCD</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password>ABCD</wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <----->
            <-------->
               
            </------->
        </--------->
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Response Body:

```
Connection=close
Pragma=no-cache
Content-Length=359
Cache-Control=no-cache
Content-Type=text/xml; charset=utf-8

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode><faultstring>The requested operation was rejected. Please consult with your administrator.Your support ID is: 17985204652528471489</faultstring><detail/></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: in "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br" I remove the br and it works but with another error as below :

Connection=close
Content-Length=311
Content-Type=text/html; charset=us-ascii

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request is badly formed.</p>
</BODY></HTML>

Answer (score 0):

in "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br" I remove the br and it works but with another error as below :

```
Connection=close
Content-Length=311
Content-Type=text/html; charset=us-ascii

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request is badly formed.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

I edited the Header as follow and it works fine.
some headers are extra and there is no need for most of them

```
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
SOAPAction: URL
Content-Type: text/xml
```

Comment: could you kindly paste sample request for any operation like 'GetAllowedServicesForCountry', mask the original data (just want to confirm fields how they look). I am getting 'page not found error' now when i use the headers you mentioned above in Postman.
Thanks